# Kotlin - Implementing a central call stack for async coroutines?

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

Let's say I have a bunch of async coroutines. These coroutines also spawn additional coroutines as they run. However, some coroutines are designed to stall indefinitely until a certain function is called somewhere. I want to detect that all coroutines, as well as their children and all descendants, have all reached suspension points - i.e. they are all waiting for something else to happen, before calling this certain function to "unclog" the coroutines that stall indefinitely. Sort of like a nextTick() function in node.js.

Is it possible to do so? How do I listen for suspension points?

Comment: Looks like you need your own `CoroutineDispatcher` implementation. All the coroutines will have to use it as their context, this can't mix with `UI` or `CommonPool` contexts.

Comment: Specifically, you must install your [continuation interceptor](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-coroutines/blob/master/kotlin-coroutines-informal.md#continuation-interceptor).

Comment: So an idea is to wrap the CommonPool dispatcher with some other wrapper class? What should I fire when a coroutine is suspended? Or when it resolves? I think extra care needs to be taken such that the "awaiting" coroutines resume before the resolution of a coroutine. I.e. if A awaits B, A must resume before B.

Comment: Yes, a wrapping approach could work. You have to know the exact reason why a coroutine was suspended and take control of resuming only those that actually await your signal. Now that I say it like that, maybe you don't even need a coroutine dispatcher. You just need a `suspend fun` that registers the coroutine as waiting for the signal. Basically, you're reimplementing the `CyclicBarrier` in the coroutine world, maybe googling for that could help as well.